# How to get the Row Headers functionality in ExtJs?

Tags: javascript, json, extjs, matrix, extjs4

I want to render something like depicted below :

```
+-----------------+------------+---------------+
|                 |  Column 1  |    Column 2   |
+------------------------------+---------------+
|  Row Header 1   |    ...     |               |
+------------------------------+---------------+
|  Row Header 2   |            |               |
+------------------------------+---------------+
|  Row Header 3   |            |               |
+----------------------------------------------+
```

I understand the way to achieve the column headers, there are lot of documentation available as well. e.g. http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/extjs-build/examples/build/KitchenSink/ext-theme-neptune/#grouped-header-grid

But I couldn't get the one for having Row Headers. How do I achieve it and render the data corresponding to row and column attributes, say from Jason file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, your grid would have three columns:

```
columns:[{
    dataIndex:'rowHeader'
},{
    text:'Column 1',
    dataIndex:'column1'
},{
    text:'Column 2',
    dataIndex:'column2'
}]
```

and load the data from a store with the model `fields:['rowHeader','column1','column2']`

which would, if it is a JSON store, expect the data to be submitted to him by the server in the format

```
{success:true,data:[
    {rowHeader:'RowHeader 1',column1:'',column2:''},
    {rowHeader:'RowHeader 2',column1:'',column2:''},
    {rowHeader:'RowHeader 3',column1:'',column2:''}
]}
```

If you want to display data that comes in other formats than that, e.g. the format often used for sparse matrices:

```
{rowHeader:'RowHeader 1',columnHeader:'ColumnHeader 1',value:''},
{rowHeader:'RowHeader 2',columnHeader:'ColumnHeader 1',value:''},
{rowHeader:'RowHeader 3',columnHeader:'ColumnHeader 1',value:''},
{rowHeader:'RowHeader 1',columnHeader:'ColumnHeader 2',value:''},
{rowHeader:'RowHeader 2',columnHeader:'ColumnHeader 2',value:''},
{rowHeader:'RowHeader 3',columnHeader:'ColumnHeader 2',value:''},
{rowHeader:'RowHeader 1',columnHeader:'ColumnHeader 3',value:''},
{rowHeader:'RowHeader 2',columnHeader:'ColumnHeader 3',value:''},
{rowHeader:'RowHeader 3',columnHeader:'ColumnHeader 3',value:''}
```

you will have to manually transform the data into aforementioned format, because ExtJS grid just can't process any format that does not have one record per row.

If you would like to know how to make the RowHeader cells look like headers:

Basically, it comes down to defining a tdCls, and possibly also a renderer, on the column. You may want to have a look at the api docs at http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.Column-cfg-tdCls and at http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.Column-cfg-renderer

Then, there is the How To Style ExtJS Grid Cells guide at http://skirtlesden.com/articles/styling-extjs-grid-cells

Comment: In my case, the columns will be loaded dynamically, meaning we dont know how many of them and hence can't fix the fields in Json file. But still your answer gave me some direction which I can use to render stuff. Thank you so much!

Comment: It would be great if you also throw some light on how to deal with the scenario I mentioned in previous comment.

Comment: Alexander, pls answer relevant question here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28342132/how-to-have-headers-in-first-column-instead-of-regular-headers-in-top-row

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a fixed JSON structure, you will have to send a schema.
I would recommend to use a json format which is ready-to-eat for `grid.reconfigure`.

```
{"schema":[{dataIndex:'t1',name:'T1'}],"data":[{t1:'Val'},{t1:'Valo'}]}
```

Now you wouldn't load this into a store directly, but use an `Ext.Ajax.request`, then prepare the store  (just create a new one with the fields from the schema) and the grid (`grid.reconfigure(columns,store)`), before putting the data into the store using `store.loadRawData`.